# json data not getting loaded into UITextView in swift

Tags: json, swift, nsdictionary

```
class ViewController:ViewController,UITextViewDelegate{


@IBOutlet weak var newTextView: UITextView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    newTextView.delegate = self

    dataFun()
}

func dataFun()
{
    let url : String = "http:xyz/abc"

    let request : NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest()

    request.URL = NSURL(string: url)

    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    print("Start")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

        do {
            let jsonResult: NSDictionary! = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options:NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers) as? NSDictionary

            print("In method\(jsonResult)")

           // let data = jsonResult["description"]
           // print(data!)


            if (jsonResult != nil)
            {
                // process jsonResult
                print("Data added")

                let test:String = jsonResult["description"] as! String
                print(test)
                self.newTextView.text = test

            } else {
                print("No Data")
                // couldn't load JSON, look at error
               }
        }
        catch {
            print("Error Occured")
        }
        }
        .resume()


}
```

In my app I am going to call services from API

I can see my json data in console.

that data is not show in `textviewController`

it shows fatal error:

> unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

and then crash the app

Comment: where is the code that you are setting the textView.text?

Comment: Show your json response here

Comment: description = "We are xxxx, a fresh and innovative company that was established in the latter half of 2012.The idea for our company came when our executives were trying to find employees in the IT field, and were going through a myriad of difficulties in finding the right candidates, it was cutting in to our costs of finding an employee as well focusing our available time away from the duties they needed to perform. As a way of reducing the cost and time in finding a suitable employee ,xxxx was created";

    responseCode = 200;

    Id = 13;

    updatedOn = 1475587756000;

Comment: iam try to print 'description' in my UITextView

Answer (score 0):

Make sure `@IBOutlet weak var newTextView: UITextView!` is set up correctly.

Make sure `let test:String = jsonResult["description"] as! String` doesn't crash. JSON has field description and it's a string.